# Convert existing Cov Matrix to block diagonal

Tags: r, matrix

I have an existing covariance matrix and I would like to convert it to become block diagonal based on which groups the individual columns belong to (e.g. 1st 2 rows/columns are group 1, next are group 2 etc.) Is there a simple way of doing this:

Below is an example of what I have:

```
m1 <- matrix(1:16, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(m1) <- colnames(m1 ) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')

   a  b  c  d
a  1  2  3  4
b  5  6  7  8
c  9 10 11 12
d 13 14 15 16
```

I have 2 groups:

Group 1: 'a', 'b'

Group 2: 'c', 'd'

and what I would like:

```
   a  b  c  d
a  1  2  0  0
b  5  6  0  0
c  0  0 11 12
d  0  0 15 16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`linpk`](https://github.com/benjaminrich/linpk) package with `blockdiag` function where you use two subsets of the groups you want like this:

```r
m1 <- matrix(1:16, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(m1) <- colnames(m1 ) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
library(linpk)
blockdiag(m1[c("a", "b"), c("a", "b")], m1[c("c", "d"), c("c", "d")])
#>   a b  c  d
#> a 1 2  0  0
#> b 5 6  0  0
#> c 0 0 11 12
#> d 0 0 15 16
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Nice and short solution, appreciate it!!!

Comment: How would I modify this if I have 3 groups?

Comment: I think I got it, nevermind, just had to add the respective blocks as arguments)

Answer (score 8):

Using a `for` loop.

```
g <- list(c('a', 'b'), c('c', 'd'))
for (x in g) m1[!rownames(m1) %in% x, colnames(m1) %in% x] <- 0
m1
#   a b  c  d
# a 1 2  0  0
# b 5 6  0  0
# c 0 0 11 12
# d 0 0 15 16
```

Answer (score 8):

We could use using logical indexing using the `which` function:
With `which` we set the elements outside of each group to 0 using logical indexing. So we do not need a loop. This could be more efficient in larges matrices.

```
group1 <- c('a', 'b')
group2 <- c('c', 'd')

# logical indices for all groups
idx_group1 <- which(colnames(m1) %in% group1)
idx_group2 <- which(colnames(m1) %in% group2)


m1[-idx_group1, idx_group1] <- 0
m1[idx_group1, -idx_group1] <- 0
m1[-idx_group2, idx_group2] <- 0
m1[idx_group2, -idx_group2] <- 0

m1
```

```
  a b  c  d
a 1 2  0  0
b 5 6  0  0
c 0 0 11 12
d 0 0 15 16
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way.

```r
fun <- function(x, groups) {
  y <- matrix(0, nrow(x), ncol(x), dimnames = dimnames(x))
  for(i in seq_along(groups)) 
    y[groups[[i]], groups[[i]]] <- 1L
  x * y
}

m1 <- matrix(1:16, ncol=4, byrow=TRUE)
rownames(m1) <- colnames(m1 ) <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
group1 <- c("a", "b")
group2 <- c("c", "d")

fun(m1, list(group1, group2))
#>   a b  c  d
#> a 1 2  0  0
#> b 5 6  0  0
#> c 0 0 11 12
#> d 0 0 15 16
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

We can use `tcrossprod` + `table` + `stack` to create a mask matrix, e.g.,

```
> tcrossprod(table(stack(setNames(g, seq_along(g)))))
      values
values a b c d
     a 1 1 0 0
     b 1 1 0 0
     c 0 0 1 1
     d 0 0 1 1
```

such that

```
> m1 * tcrossprod(table(stack(setNames(g, seq_along(g)))))
  a b  c  d
a 1 2  0  0
b 5 6  0  0
c 0 0 11 12
d 0 0 15 16
```

where

```
g <- list(c("a", "b"), c("c", "d"))
```